# How do I redirect stdout to a variable and stderr to a file in ubuntu?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

I have this command and it outputs a warning and the result that I have. I want the result in a variable so I can use it later on in a shell script and redirect error to log file.

This is what I have got so far.

```
wp post create --post_type=post --post_title='A future post' --post_status=publish --post_date='2015-01-01 07:00:00' --user=wordpress --url=vip.local/fusion --post_name='mock-post' --porcelain --quiet 2>&1 1>stdout.log | tee stderr.log
```

but I want the stdout to be in a variable and leave any error to `stderr.log`

This is the output from the command

```
PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3457
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/src/wp-cli/bin/wp:0
PHP   2. include() /usr/local/src/wp-cli/bin/wp:4
PHP   3. include() phar:///usr/local/src/wp-cli/bin/wp/php/boot-phar.php:5
PHP   4. require() phar:///usr/local/src/wp-cli/bin/wp/php/wp-cli.php:26
PHP   5. do_action() phar:///usr/local/src/wp-cli/bin/wp/php/wp-settings-cli.php:349
PHP   6. call_user_func_array() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:503
PHP   7. wp_widgets_init() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:503
PHP   8. do_action() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/default-widgets.php:1650
PHP   9. call_user_func_array() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:503
PHP  10. __lambda_func() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php:503
PHP  11. register_widget() /srv/www/wp-content/plugins/polldaddy/polldaddy-org.php(1075) : runtime-created function:1
PHP  12. WP_Widget_Factory->register() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/widgets.php:720
PHP  13. PD_Top_Rated->PD_Top_Rated() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/widgets.php:591
PHP  14. WP_Widget->WP_Widget() /srv/www/wp-content/plugins/polldaddy/polldaddy-org.php:950
PHP  15. _deprecated_constructor() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/widgets.php:176
PHP  16. trigger_error() /srv/www/wp/wp-includes/functions.php:3457
132048 # << This is the stdout
```

The number `132048` is the output I want in a variable and PHP Notice is stderr. I could have read stdout to a variable again but I thought there's must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the output of a command in a variable by using backticks and redirect stderr to a file using `2>`:

```
VARIABLE=`command --opt arg 2> stderr.log`
```

In your case, something like this should work:

```
VARIABLE=`wp post create --post_type=post --post_title='A future post' --post_status=publish --post_date='2015-01-01 07:00:00' --user=wordpress --url=vip.local/fusion --post_name='mock-post' --porcelain --quiet 2> stderr.log`
```